# Airflow: How to template or pass the output of a Python Callable function as arguments to other tasks?

Tags: airflow

I'm new to Airflow and working on making my ETL pipeline more re-usable. Originally, I had a few lines of top-level code that would determine the job_start based on a few user input parameters, but I found through much searching that this would trigger at [every heartbeat](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/templating/) which was causing some unwanted behavior in truncating the table.

Now I am investigating wrapping this top level code into a Python Callable so it is secure from the refresh, but I am unsure of the best way to pass the output to my other tasks. The gist of my code is below:

```
def get_job_dts(): 

     #Do something to determine the appropriate job_start_dt and job_end_dt

     #Package up as a list as inputs to other PythonCallables using op_args

     job_params = [job_start_dt, job_end_dt]

     return job_params

t0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'get_dates'
    python_callable = get_job_dts
    dag=dag
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
     task_id = 'task_1'
     ,python_callable=first_task
     ,op_args=job_params #<-- How do I send job_params to op_args??
     ,dag=dag
)

t0 >> t1
```

I've searched around and hear mentions of jinja templates, variables, or xcoms, but I'm fuzzy on how to implement it. Does anyone have an example I could look at where I can save that list into a variable that can be used by my other tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to push your value into XCom in get_job_dts, and pull the value back from Xcom in first_task.

```
def get_job_dts(**kwargs): 

     #Do something to determine the appropriate job_start_dt and job_end_dt

     #Package up as a list as inputs to other PythonCallables using op_args

    job_params = [job_start_dt, job_end_dt]

    # Push job_params into XCom
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='job_params', value=job_params)
    return job_params


def first_task(ti, **kwargs):
    # Pull job_params into XCom
    job_params = ti.xcom_pull(key='job_params')
    # And then do the rest


t0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'get_dates'
    python_callable = get_job_dts
    dag=dag
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'task_1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=first_task,
    op_args=job_params,
    dag=dag
)

t0 >> t1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you explain where "ti" comes from? I've also seen people use **context as arguments, does **kwargs == **context? Finally, do all DAGs that implement XCOM whether pulling or pushing need providecontext=True? Or is it only the DAGs that pull?

Comment: This code is syntactically incorrect and not reproducible, could you provide a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

As [RyantheCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9465561/ryanthecoder) mentioned, XCOM is the way to go. My implementation is geared towards the tutorial where I implicitly perform a push automatically from a return value in a PythonCallable.

I am still confused by the difference in passing in (ti, **kwargs) vs. using (**context) to the function that is pulling. Also, where does "ti" come from?

Any clarifications appreciated.

```
def get_job_dts(**kwargs): 

     #Do something to determine the appropriate job_start_dt and job_end_dt

     #Package up as a list as inputs to other PythonCallables using op_args

     job_params = [job_start_dt, job_end_dt]

     # Automatically pushes to XCOM, refer to: Airflow XCOM tutorial: https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms
     return job_params

def first_task(**context):

    # Change task_ids to whatever task pushed the XCOM vars you need, rest are standard notation
    job_params = job_params = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_dates')

    # And then do the rest


t0 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'get_dates'
    python_callable = get_job_dts
    dag=dag
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'task_1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=first_task,
    dag=dag
)

t0 >> t1
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass a task instance explicitly, but you should use either ```**kwargs```or ```**context```(which is the same, context is just another name for kwargs) in line with ```provide_context=True```. See https://bcb.github.io/airflow/execute-context as well for the structure of the context.

Comment: Airflow has some good examples on their github. https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py

I believe you've got it right in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned changing task start time and end time dynamically, I supposed what you need is to create dynamic dag rather than just pass the args to dag. Especially, changing start time and interval without changing dag name will cause unexpected result, it will highly suggested not to do so. So you can refer to this [link](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) to see if this strategy can help.